# How to get specific element in foreach loop in c#?

Tags: c#, foreach

I have a list and I need to update some of the data in this list.

I have a update T-SQL query:

```
Update Report
Set ['+@Period+'] = @Amount
Where Group = 1
```

I think that I can use `foreach` for this update.

```
string period=startDate.ToString("yy/MM/dd").Substring(0, 2) + startDate.ToString("yy/MM/dd").Substring(3, 2);

foreach (var item in report)
{
   if (item.Grup == 1)
   {
      item.??? = amount; //My period names in the table like _2101, _2102 etc 
   }
}
```

I use `foreach` because I have a while condition outside of the `foreach` and the update operation will occur for other periods. How can I get the `item.period`?

--Edit--

My table looks like that and I want to update null values one by one. This method returns the report table.

[image]

Comment: What does the list look like? Expected output? Please exclude the T-SQL information from the question and just replace it with a demo list similar to your DB data as it contributes nothing to the question and allows others to quickly read through the question

Comment: "How can I get the item.period?" -- `item.period`.

Comment: @RobertHarvey period is a variable. I have item._2101, item._2102 . I want to get these ones using something like that item.period

Comment: Sounds like you need to put _2101 and _2102 into a collection within `item` so that you can iterate over it.  Hard to tell without seeing what `item` actually looks like.

Comment: @mordeby You mean "How can I get the `period` property of every item variable?" - I would agree with Robert but hard to say without you adding more information.

Comment: I add the image of the my report table, I hope it helps to me to explain my question.

Comment: Right.  So the first thing I would do with that query is run an UNPIVOT over it, so that you get a row for each column instead of multiple columns.  See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: I am trying to do this in C#. I have the SQL query to do this, I have to do this in a method. But I can not implement in C#

Comment: Do keep in minmd, that while a `foreach` loop is often quite handy, in many other cases a regular `for` loop is the better choice.

Comment: Your column format is not ideal.  It's unlikely you will find a good way to iterate over that.  Iteration is more suited to rows, not columns.  That's why I suggested the UNPIVOT.

Comment: Or, change your table format so that you get one row per date instead of multiple rows.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a good idea to store periods in columns as such if you're planning to add more. It would be easier to change your table structure so that it can support having its own table for periods.

But if for some reasons you really have to do it. You could get these columns name using the following t-sql (assuming your table is on the [dbo] schema and the columns you need all start with an underscore) :

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'Report' AND TABLE_SCHEMA='dbo' AND COLUMN_NAME LIKE '\_%' ESCAPE '\'
```

Then using these column names you could build a new query with these column names :

```
"SELECT " + string.Join(',', columnNames) + " FROM Report"
```

using [Dapper](https://github.com/DapperLib/Dapper) you could do the following :

```
IEnumerable<string> columnNames;

using (var connection = new SqlConnection(dbConnectionString))
{
    columnNames = connection.Query<string>(@"
        SELECT COLUMN_NAME
        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
        WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'Report' AND TABLE_SCHEMA='dbo' AND COLUMN_NAME LIKE '\_%' ESCAPE '\'");
}

IEnumerable<dynamic> reports;

using (var connection = new SqlConnection(dbConnectionString))
{
    reports = connection.Query("SELECT " + string.Join(',', columnNames) + " FROM Report");
}

foreach(var report in reports)
{
    report._2021 = (object)1.0;
}
```

This way you can access the values of _2101, _2102, etc.

But creating a period table to store these would make 100% more sense.